# Understanding this JS syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am practising ES6 and I have this code:

```js
const over = (...fns) => (...args) =>
  fns.map(fn => fn.apply(null, args));

const minMax = over(Math.min, Math.max);

console.log(minMax(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
console.log(minMax(1, 2, 5, 4, 3));
console.log(minMax(1, 2, 5, -4, 3));
```

The goal is to get the minimum and the maximun values between the numbers passed as arguments.

I could understand almost everything, the dynamic is very clear, with one exception, I know that `args` refers to the parameters coming from `minMax()`, but I couldn't get how the code recognize it.

My guess is: since we have two functions, `over()` and `minMax()`, when called, they are automatically read in this order, that is why the code knows that the first anonymous function refers to `over()` and the second one to `minMax()`. But this is just a guess, I don't know if I am right.

What is exactly happening here?

Comment: Take a look at [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: `minMax = over(Math.min, Math.max)`, so, kind of, `minMax = (...args) => [Math.min, Math.max].map(fn => fn.apply(null, args));`. From there, `minMax(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is `[Math.min, Math.max].map(fn => fn.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))`

Comment: `over` is a function which takes a list of functions (as `fns`) and *returns a function which takes a list of values (as `args`).* `minMax` is this *function which takes a list of values*, because it's the return value of `over`. `minMax` now, when called, maps the list of functions over the list of values.

Comment: Always think in terms of "is a function which takes X and returns Y". And remember that `(..) => (..) => ..` is shorthand for *"function which returns a function"*.

Comment: @deceze That is exactly what I wasn't getting, the 'return' part. It is very clear now. Thank you very much. If you want to edit your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Replace `(..) => ..` with `function (..) { return .. }` to perhaps make that clearer.